# C++ Adding Elements to Array and Modifying Function to Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm still a bit stuck on another part on my assignment.

Here is what the prompt is asking:

> Now you can modify the LoadMovies function to create a MovieList
>   object and add each of the Movie objects to it. The function
>   LoadMovies should return a pointer to the MovieList object. That means
>   you need to create the MovieList object dynamically and on the heap.
>
> Change the main function and store the returned MovieList pointer in a
>   variable. To test if everything works as expected, you can use the
>   PrintAll function of the MovieList object.

Here is my code so far:

```
class MovieList {

public:
    Movie* movies;
    int last_movie_index;
    int movies_size;
    int movie_count = 0;

MovieList(int size) {
    movies_size = size;
    movies = new Movie[movies_size];
    last_movie_index = -1;
}

~MovieList() {
    delete [] movies;
}

int Length() {
    return movie_count;
}

bool IsFull() {
    return movie_count == movies_size;
}

void Add(Movie const& m)
{
    if (IsFull())
    {
        cout << "Cannot add movie, list is full" << endl;
        return;
    }

    ++last_movie_index;
    movies[last_movie_index] = m;
}

void PrintAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < movie_count; i++) {
        movies[last_movie_index].PrintMovie();
    }
}

};

void ReadMovieFile(vector<string> &movies);
void LoadMovies();

enum MovieSortOrder
{
    BY_YEAR = 0,
    BY_NAME = 1,
    BY_VOTES = 2
};

int main()
{
    LoadMovies();

    // TODO:
    // You need to implement the Movie and MovieList classes and
    // the methods below so that the program will produce
    // the output described in the assignment.
    //
    // Once you have implemented everything, you should be able
    // to simply uncomment the code below and run the program.

    MovieList *movies = LoadMovies();

    //    // test methods for the Movie and MovieList classes
        //PrintAllMoviesMadeInYear(movies, 1984);
        //PrintAllMoviesWithStartLetter(movies, 'B');
        //PrintAllTopNMovies(movies, 5);

        //delete movies;
    return 0;
}

void LoadMovies()
{
    vector<string> movies;
    ReadMovieFile(movies);

    string name;
    int year;
    double rating;
    int votes;

    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++)
    {
        istringstream input_string(movies[i]);
        getline(input_string, name, '\t');
        input_string >> year >> rating >> votes;
        Movie movie (name, year, votes, rating);
        movie.PrintMovie();
    }
}
```

Now where I'm stuck at is where the professor asks me to modify the LoadMovies in the prompt and turn it into a pointer. I'm drawing blanks. Also for some reason if I try to compile it says:

```
C:\Users\Andy\Documents\C++ Homework\MovieStatisticsProgram\MovieStatsProgram.cpp:163: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     MovieList *movies = LoadMovies();
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function prototypes in the class definition.

```
class MovieList {

public:
    MovieList();    // constructor
    ~MovieList();   // destructor

    void Add(Movie const& m);
    bool IsFull();
    ... etc

private:   // Your members should be private, in general
    Movie* movies;
    int last_movie_index;
    int movies_size;
    int movie_count = 0;    
}
```

Then all of your functions should be members of your `MovieList` class so they can access the member variables, and have a `this` to refer to. For example these would be outside the class declaration.

```
int MovieList::Length(){
    // work
}

bool MovieList::IsFull(){
    // work
}
```

The same goes for `LoadMovies`, it should have the signature

```
MovieList* MovieList::LoadMovies();   // Note it returns a MovieList pointer, not void
```

Then in `main` you can make an instance

```
int main()
{
    MovieList ml = MovieList();    // instantiate a MovieList

    Movie a = Movie();   // instantiate a couple of movies
    Movie b = Movie();
    ml.Add(a);           // call the Add method
    ml.Add(b);

    MovieList* movies = ml.LoadMovies();  // Calls method from this object
}
```

As a side note, I notice there is a comment in `main` that says `//delete movies;`. Actually, since your `MovieList` object allocated the array, it **should** be responsible to clean up after itself. By that I mean the destructor should be something like this so you don't leak memory.

```
MovieList::~MovieList()
{
    delete[] movies;
    movies = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: When I do the function prototypes, my compiler will always say function cannot be overloaded and the function is overqualified.

Comment: If you defined the functions outside of `class MovieList { ... }`, then they need the scope, e.g. `MovieList::IsFull()`. If you define them within the class scope, they do not, e.g. `class MovieList { bool IsFull(); }` Note that in my above example, I closed the braces for `class MovieList` before writing the definitions for `Length` and `IsFull`.

Comment: Also, in my LoadMovies function, when I add MovieList::Add(movie), the compiler will say it cannot be called without an object, however isn't the object already in the parameter?

Comment: You must make a `Movie`, such as `Movie movie = Movie();`. Then you declare a MovieList like `MovieList ml = MovieList();`. Now you can call `Add` which is a method of MovieList as `ml.Add(movie);` See my edit in the above `main` function

Comment: Thanks again Cyber for all of your help, I just fixed the prototypes. So I see that you have the Add function called in main, I think my professor will want it in the LoadMovies function. So should I just declare another MovieList in my LoadMovies function?

Comment: Well, I'm making progress I have finally got the compiler to stop throwing errors, however now the application crashes upon opening. Here's what I added: MovieList ml = MovieList(movies.size()); so that I could use ml.Add(movie);

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an object of type MovieList().

The method "LoadMovies" only does a read and assembles a vector locally.

The function LoadMovies() returns nothing, you can't assign "nothing" to anything.

Why don't you take advantage of the methods that you already have. Each movie that is read in, needs to go into a MovieList object. Call Add() method.

Declare a MovieList object inside LoadMovies() and change the return type to return by reference/pointer to MovieList, like

```
MovieList* LoadMovies();
```

If not pass in a MovieList object by reference and fill it in.

```
void LoadMovies(MovieList& mList)
```

I think you need to look at basics in a book and go from there. This type of question might be downvoted severely.